# MD5 is 128 bits but why is it 32 characters?

Tags: hash, cryptography, md5, cryptographic-hash-function

I read some docs about md5, it said that its 128 bits, but why is it 32 characters? I can't compute the characters.

- 1 byte is 8 bits
- if 1 character is 1 byte
- then 128 bits is 128/8 = 16 bytes right?

EDIT:

SHA-1 produces 160 bits, so how many characters are there?

Comment: Can you post a link to the docs you reference?

Comment: @don: Sorry, its my lecturer notes. But ba__friend has answered my question, and i test it here: http://www.miraclesalad.com/webtools/md5.php, and its really hexadecimal characters only, it makes much more sense to me now. I will vote his answer as best answer

Comment: I think my answer goes into more detail on this than any others. [If you're new to computer programming and asking this question and want a through answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41618070/124486)

Comment: It's not a silly question. Once upon a time you also didn't know how many HEX chars represented one byte.

Comment: A quick python one liner to calculate the bit length of a hash is `((1 << (n*4))-1).bit_length()` where n is the length of the hash in hexadecimal

Answer (score 136, accepted):

32 chars as hexdecimal representation, thats 2 chars per byte.

Comment: 1 byte is represented by a two digit hexdecimal number, like 255 = ff.

Comment: so 1 byte is 2 chars which means 16 bits is 2 chars then 128/16 = 8. So 8 of 2 chars = 16 chars is required then? Why 32?

Comment: Because each hex character can be represented by 4 bits. So if it is 128 bits it is 128/4 = 32 hex characters. Even though each "char" will be encoded as a utf8 or ascii which will make the hex representation size 32*8= 256 bits.

Comment: This is a really poor answer. My answer goes into details on this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41618070/124486

Comment: @KorayTugay "so 1 byte is 2 chars which means 16 bits is 2 chars" - 1 byte != 16 bits.

Answer (score 48):

I wanted summerize some of the answers into one post.

First, don't think of the MD5 hash as a character string but as a hex number.  Therefore, each digit is a hex digit (0-15 or 0-F) and represents four bits, not eight.

Taking that further, one byte or eight bits are represented by two hex digits, e.g. b'`1111 1111`' = `0xFF` = `255`.

MD5 hashes are 128 bits in length and generally represented by 32 hex digits.

SHA-1 hashes are 160 bits in length and generally represented by 40 hex digits.

For the SHA-2 family, I think the hash length can be one of a pre-determined set.  So SHA-512 can be represented by 128 hex digits.

Again, this post is just based on previous answers.

Answer (score 37):

## A hex "character" (nibble) is different from a "character"

To be clear on the bits vs byte, vs characters.

- 1 byte is 8 bits (for our purposes)
- 8 bits provides `2**8` possible combinations: 256 combinations

When you look at a **hex character,**

- 16 combinations of `[0-9] + [a-f]`: the full range of `0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,a,b,c,d,e,f`
- 16 is less than 256, so one one hex character does **not** store a byte.
- 16 is `2**4`: that means one hex character can store 4 bits in a byte (half a byte).
- Therefore, two hex characters, can store 8 bits, `2**8` combinations.
- A byte represented as a hex character is `[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]` and that represents both halfs of a byte (we call a half-byte a [nibble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nibble)).

When you look at a **regular single-byte character,** (we're totally going to skip multi-byte and wide-characters here)

- It can store far more than 16 combinations.
- The capabilities of the *character* are determined by the *encoding.* For instance, the [ISO 8859-1 that stores an entire byte, stores all this stuff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)
- All that stuff takes the entire `2**8` range.
- If a hex-character in an `md5()` could store all that, you'd see all the lowercase letters, all the uppercase letters, all the punctuation and things like `¡°ÀÐàð`, whitespace like (newlines, and tabs), and control characters (which you can't even see and many of which aren't in use).

So they're clearly different and I hope that provides the best break down of the differences.

Comment: What does this "In which order is actually spec or platform dependent" actually mean? Would love to see this explained a bit more.

Comment: @KumarM I'm going to delete that because I don't think it's actually relevant to the conversation at all, and it's badly worded.

Answer (score 29):

MD5 yields hexadecimal digits (0-15 / 0-F), so they are four bits each. 128 / 4 = 32 characters.

SHA-1 yields hexadecimal digits too (0-15 / 0-F), so 160 / 4 = 40 characters.

(Since they're mathematical operations, most hashing functions' output is commonly represented as hex digits.)

You were probably thinking of ASCII text characters, which are 8 bits.

Comment: thank you so much.. i have much more clearer picture in my head now!!

Comment: note: ascii-charset contains non-printable symbols.

Comment: I tried to break this down a little more explicitly http://stackoverflow.com/a/41618070/124486

Answer (score 14):

**One hex digit** = 1 [nibble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nibble) (four-bits)

**Two hex digits** = 1 byte (eight-bits)

**MD5** = 32 hex digits

**32 hex digits** = 16 bytes ( 32 / 2)

**16 bytes** = 128 bits (16 * 8)

*The same applies to SHA-1 except it's 40 hex digits long.*

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 9):

That's 32 hex characters - 1 hex character is 4 bits.

Answer (score 3):

Those are hexidecimal digits, not characters. One digit = 4 bits.

Answer (score 2):

They're not actually characters, they're hexadecimal digits.

Answer (score 0):

For clear understanding, copy the MD5 calculated 128 bit hash value in the [Binary to Hex convertor](https://www.asciitohex.com/) and see the length of the Hex value. You will get 32 characters Hex characters.